# python: ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, python-c-extension

im trying to install my function written in c (**with python3 setup.py install**) but python raise *ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_costFunction)*
error!

**costFunction.c:**

```c
static PyObject *costFunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("d", 0); // or anything!
}

static PyMethodDef costFunction_methods[] = {
    {"costFunction", (PyCFunction)costFunction, METH_VARARGS, "cost function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef costFunctionmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,"costFunction", NULL, -1, costFunction_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_costFunction(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&costFunctionmodule);
}
```

**setup.py:**

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='costFunction', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('costFunction', ['costFunction.c'],include_dirs=['include'])])
```

**external library: tinyexpr**

i'm using **linux mint 18 with python 3.5.2**

**EDIT:**
python3-dev version is 3.5.1-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i used an dirty trick!

compiled c code(without python.h and any python datatype in C) with:

```
gcc -fPIC -Wall -O3 costFunction.c -o costFunction.so -shared  -fopenmp
```

and used python ctypes module to load and use it:

```
dll = ctypes.CDLL("./costFunction.so")
costFunction = dll.cost_function
costFunction.restype = ctypes.c_double
costFunction.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_int]
```